# Creating Latex template for a given format: Problems with line spacing and list indentation

Tags: spacing, sectioning, alignment

I am trying to write a Latex template for the format shown in following figure.
In the figure only vertical spaces are given and 1 = 0.1 in. I have written a partial code and unable to complete it. I am trying to use *vspace* with *Center heading* but it is giving spacing of more than 0.2 inches. Also, the nested listed is not properly indented.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
% Change font to Helvetica which is same as Arial.
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

% Set margin of the paper. % Set top and bottom margins
\usepackage[a4paper,
    left = 1.5in, right = 0.5in, top = 0.5in, bottom = 0.5in]{geometry}

% Define a new command
\newcommand{\CentreHeading}[1]{\begin{center} \begin{large} 
\MakeUppercase{\textbf{#1}} \end{large} \end{center}} % Space of 2 units 
below Centre Heading.
\newcommand{\SideHeading}[1]{\noindent\textbf{#1}} % Space of 2 units below 
         Side Heading.
\usepackage{titlecaps}
\newcommand{\ParaHeading}[1]{\titlecap{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\SubparaHeading}[1]{\titlecap{\textbf{#1}}}

% Define top level numbering.
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{wide, topsep = 0mm, partopsep = 0mm, parsep = 0in, 
 itemsep = 0.16666in, labelindent = 0pt, leftmargin = 0in, labelsep = 0.5in}
 \newenvironment{mylist} { \begin{enumerate} }{ \end{enumerate} }

\begin{document}
\CentreHeading{Something for centre heading}
\SideHeading{Observations}
\begin{mylist}
    \item This is the first line of first itemize list and should be 1. Please ignore all the other text in this line. This is all garbage. 
    \item This is the second line of first itemize list and should be 2. Please ignore all the other text in this line. This is all garbage.
    \begin{mylist}
        \item This is the first line of second (nested) itemize list and should be a. Please ignore all the other text in this line. This is all garbage.
        \item This is the second line of second (nested) itemize list and should be b. Please ignore all the other text in this line. This is all garbage.
    \end{mylist}
    \item This is the third line of first itemize list and should be c. Please ignore all the other text in this line. This is all garbage.
\end{mylist}
\end{document}
```

Comment: **(0)** Welcome! **(1)** Is there no Sub-Sub-Paragraph Heading? **(2)** Are you the first who implements a LaTeX version of this requirements at your organization?

Comment: @Dr.Manuel (0) Thank you. (1)There is no sub-sub paragraph heading yet. I think I can define it in case we need. (2) yes, I am the first one.

Comment: But how do you switch logically from sub-paragraph to sub-sub level?

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=1in}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
{\bf{\large} CENTER HEADING}
\end{center}\\
\section{Paragraph Heading}
% You can write all the text here
\subsection{Sub Paragraph Heading}% you can replace it
% put your text here.
\subsubsection{ Sub Sub paragraph heading} % you can replace it
% enter your text here

\end{document}
```

%If you want a in place of `1.1`, then replace it with `%%\subsubsection*{a. Tex}`. Here you do not need packages.

Comment: It looks like the `OP` meant that `TOC` part.... Is your suggestion works for that? ...

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=1in}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
{\bf{\large} CENTER HEADING}
\end{center}

\section{Paragraph Heading}
% You can write all the text here
 The nonlinear Schrodinger equation is a most important equation governing many physics phenomena. It has thus been studied in many previous papers. The present authors adopt a somewhat new approach  by using two different averaged complex potentials.  I think that this approach is interesting, and that the present manuscript thus deserves to be published.

\subsection{Sub Paragraph Heading}% you can replace it
% put your text here.
However, above eq. (24) which describes the Gibbon potential I think that the readers would like to see a reference, as (24) is not familiar to most readers. In addition, I suggest that the flowing minor misprints are corrected:
\subsubsection{ Sub Sub paragraph heading} % you can replace it
% enter your text here
Thanks for the  comments.  Corrections suggested  are incorporated in the revised manuscript. We have also changed the title and additional text is added. There was a sign mistake in the potential which we have corrected. Regarding the Stenflo and Gibbons potentials, the exact references are given.  The page number 1735 is corrected to 1733.
\section*{(2) Paragraph heading}

We agree that many may not know the potential form therefore we have added exact location of references for these two potentials.
\begin{center}
Something for center heading
\end{center}
\section*{Observations}
\section*{First list}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item This is the first line of first itemize list and should be 1. Please ignore all the other text in this line. This is all garbage. 
    \item This is the second line of first itemize list and should be 2. Please ignore all the other text in this line. This is all garbage.
\end{enumerate}  
\section*{Second  
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item This is the first line of second (nested) itemize list and should be a. Please ignore all the other text in this line. This is all garbage.
        \item This is the second line of second (nested) itemize list and should be b. Please ignore all the other text in this line. This is all garbage.
    \end{enumerate}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item This is the third line of first itemize list and should be c. Please ignore all the other text in this line. This is all garbage.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

This is a simple document. I have added my text in it which you can delete it. You do not need additional coding. In the last I have added star for an example. Please test it.